# Sentry source map upload issue | Reac JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry, source-maps

I am trying to integrate sentry in my react js application. Facing some issues uploading source maps -
It gives me a 413 error - which implies the file size is too large. I got to know that the max size allowed is 20 MB but my source maps (all files combined) are less than 20 MB

Have tried uploading via two method -

1. Sentry webpack plugin
2. Sentry-cli

Still facing the same issue. Can someone help me